# Plurality of [part-of-speech] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

OK, firstly I apologise for being a bit pedantic. But I am wondering whether there is a particular reason why [part-of-speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/part-of-speech) is not plural (i.e. [parts-of-speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parts-of-speech)). I only bring this up because it would seem that most tags are plural where appropriate, e.g. [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), [pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns), [possessives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessives).

Comment: I don't know, but it might be because the tag is about identifying which singular part of speech a word should be categorized as being. We pluralize the other questions predicated on the fact that we have more than one question of that sort, but pluralizing parts of speech comes closer to referring to the parts as a collective whole than separate instances of each, or at least more than one of those categories simultaneously. This could be made ore congruent by renaming the tag "lexical categories" if it's really such a bother, although the present name is more traditional.

Comment: Don't expect the tag system to make sense, or to be helpful. It doesn't and it isn't. It was made by random additions of terminology from different centuries, with no consistency or correlation, and it represents nothing whatsoever. I ignore it, and recommend you do too. Sorry, folks; I know some of you love it, but it's a dead loss.